# CABasicAnimation is finishing much faster than the timer

Tags: swift, animation, timer

I am trying to make a timer with a circular progress bar using CABasicAnimation like this:
[image]

But, for some reason, the progress bar would always fill up way before the timer actually finishes. The difference between the progress bar and the timer always varies depending on the length of the timer.

Here is my code for the timer:

```
@IBOutlet var timerContainer: UIView!
@IBOutlet var timerLabel: UILabel!

var minutes = 0
var seconds = 30
var timer = Timer()
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

func displayTimer() {
    if seconds < 10 {
        timerLabel.text = "\(minutes):0\(seconds)"
    }
    else {
        timerLabel.text = "\(minutes):\(seconds)"
    }
}

@objc func timerTick() {
    
    seconds -= 1
    
    if seconds <= 0 && minutes == 0 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
    else {
        if seconds == -1 {
            minutes -= 1
            seconds = 59
        }
    }
    displayTimer()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    displayTimer()
    
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: timerContainer.center, radius: 35, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    
    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath

    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 5
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    
    
    shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
    
    view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)
    
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    
    
}

@IBAction func start() {
    
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerTick), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    
    let basicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    basicAnimation.toValue = 1
    basicAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    basicAnimation.duration = CFTimeInterval(minutes * 60 + seconds)
    basicAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    
    shapeLayer.add(basicAnimation, forKey: "begin")
    
}
```

Any thoughts on how to fix it or why it is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your arc goes from -π/2 to 2π. That's more than a full circle. I suspect it gets truncated to a 2π full circle.

Shouldn't your arc go from -π/2 to 3π/2 to give you a full circle that starts at π/2?

Comment: @andy_V so that was it?